# Can we add windows 2019 as agent node in Jenkins 1.596.2. Is it compatible?

Tags: jenkins, compatibility, hudson, windows-server-2019

Can we add windows 2019 as agent node in Jenkins 1.596.2. Is it compatible? we are unable to location any official documentation. Please suggest?

Comment: Did you try it? Agent runs on Java. Also, 1.592 very old and vulnerable, strongly suggest upgrade to [2.x](https://www.jenkins.io/download/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for compatibility before implementing it. Since the used code structure is old and using older plugins. So i am bit afraid if I donot find those plugins in jenkins version 2.x or the latest one that's why I was resisting myself to download new jenkins.

Comment: However I am wondering if windows 2019 is compatible with old version of Jenkins?